# Listbox selection produces Cannot Animate Immutable Object error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a WPF 4 application. It contains 2 listboxes.

The first has a list of available matches. when a match is selected the selection is used as the DataContext for a details grid displaying details of the match. Additionally a storyboard is played and the 2nd Listbox comes into view displaying the available markets.

This all works fine.

Problem is when a market is selected from the 2nd listbox the app crashes and I get :

> InvalidOperationException was
> unhandled
>
> Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on
> an immutable object instance

I don't know why this is happening since the Markets Listbox doesn't try to play any animation. Could it be interfering with the selection from the match list??
I tried resetting the details datacontext when a selection is made in the MarketsList but that didnt work.

Here's the xaml for the two ListBoxes

```
       <StackPanel x:Name="Connected" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxMatches" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle1}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MatchesDataTemplate}" SelectionChanged="ListBoxMatches_SelectionChanged" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Border x:Name="border1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="20" Padding="15" Margin="-400,0,400,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Markets">
                <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxCurrentMarkets" SelectionChanged="ListBoxCurrentMarkets_SelectionChanged" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
```

This is the code for the SelectionChanged event for the ListBoxMatches:

```
 private void ListBoxMatches_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListBoxMatches.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                var selectedMatch = (Match)ListBoxMatches.SelectedItem;
                if (MatchData.DataContext == null)
                {
                    MatchData.DataContext = selectedMatch;
                    Storyboard PlayMatch = (Storyboard)FindResource("MatchSelected");
                    BeginStoryboard(PlayMatch);
                }
                else if (MatchData.DataContext != selectedMatch)
                {
                    MatchData.DataContext = selectedMatch;
                }
            }
        }
```

If you need anymore code(like the storyboard xaml) please let me know.

If anyone knows why and whats going on please help.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I made the change recommended by Daniel but I must have done something wrong as it's not working.
This is the code just where I set the items source:

```
 List<Market> TestList = new List<Market>();
                Market market = new Market { ID = 0, MarketName = "CorrectScore" };
                TestList.Add(market);
                market = new Market { ID = 1, MarketName = "Match Odds" };
                TestList.Add(market);                
                ListBoxCurrentMarkets.ItemsSource = TestList;
```

This is the xaml for the listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxCurrentMarkets" SelectionChanged="ListBoxCurrentMarkets_SelectionChanged" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle1}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Market" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MarketName, Converter={x:Static local:MyCloneConverter.Instance}}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

and this is the CloneConverter:

```
public class MyCloneConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public static MyCloneConverter Instance = new MyCloneConverter();

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Freezable)
            {
                value = (value as Freezable).Clone();
            }

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

    }
```

Please take a look and tell me what you think? I put a breakpoint in the valueconverter and it's not getting hit. Also the item's in the listbox are showing up it's only when a selection is made that the error occurs.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is the xaml for the animation. The animation moves 2 negatively margined borders into positive margin(ie from out of screen into screen). There is a border which contains MatchDetails(textblocks databound to a Match), the one in question is a Border which contains the available markets ListBox.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MatchSelected">
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="borderMatchData">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,-400,0,400"/>
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="borderMarkets">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-400,0,400,0"/>
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

This is the code for playing the storyboard from the selectionchanged event for the MatchesListBox:

```
MatchData.DataContext = selectedMatch;
                    Storyboard PlayMatch = (Storyboard)FindResource("MatchSelected");
                    BeginStoryboard(PlayMatch);
```

This is the xaml for the BorderMArkets:

```
<Border x:Name="borderMarkets" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="20" Padding="15" Margin="-400,0,400,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Markets">
                <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxCurrentMarkets" SelectionChanged="ListBoxCurrentMarkets_SelectionChanged" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle1}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Market" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MarketName, Converter={StaticResource CloneConverter}}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
```

**UPDATE**

This is the template that was causing all the problems(I think)

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="#FF807F7F">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF3D3B3B"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFA71616"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFA71616"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF18E526"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/26/cannotanimateimmutableobjectinstance.aspx

Basically, this happens if you animate a databound property.

Comment: So it's because it's trying to animate and bind at the same time? if I apply the ListBox items source after the animation will that work?

Comment: I don't think this would help. You should use the solution presented in the article, namely specifying the an IValueConverter, which returns a clone of any freezable object. The `MyCloneConverter` class in the example should work just fine for you, too.

Comment: Daniel I tried it but it's not working. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I'll post my updated code. Please take a look.

Comment: The breakpoint should definitely trigger. What happens if you add `MyCloneConverter` as a resource to the XAML (`<src:MyCloneConverter  x:Key="cloneConverter"/>`) and reference this (`Converter={StaticResource cloneConverter}`)

Comment: It's hitting the break point when I do that. When it reaches "if (value is Freezable)" it skips it and returns the original value. Is it necessary to check if value is freezable? Value is a string from an INPC class.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why the `MyCloneConverter` code insists on returning a Freezable clone. I don't see any harm in removing that test, and just return `value.Clone()`.

Comment: I get an 'Object doesn't contain a definition for Clone error if I do that. Also  "value = (value as Freezable).Clone();" gives an object instance error when I run it. Are string's clonable?

Comment: Yes, strings are [clonable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.clone(v=VS.90).aspx). But we are going to the wrong track down here. The issue described in the blog is about WPF objects (DependencyObject derived), supporting animation. You, on the other hand, are binding to a simple System.String. I'm afraid, my own "answer" probably doesn't apply to your problem. Other sources for this error are described here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebuggingAnimations.html.

Comment: Can you post the animation part of the XAML?

Comment: Thank you. I have seen that link but I didn't really understand which one applied to me and how i might fix it. I presume it must be ' animating a value that is currently databound'. What do you think? I have posted the animation xaml. The animation is triggered when a selection is made from a list of available matches.

Comment: No, you are animating the `Margin` member, which isn't data bound (at least it's not visible in the code you posted). So `borderMatchData` refers to a `FrameworkElement` derived object? If so, did you give it an initial value in your XAML (= local value)?

Comment: I've just posted the xaml for the border and it's contents. Give an initial value to the Border? what do you mean?

Comment: I meant the `Margin="-400,0,400,0"` bit, so it's ok. I'm at the limit of my knowledge here, too. Next step would be to comment out selected parts (start with the `TextBlock` in XAML), then maybe remove the databinding, to see when the error is triggered.

Comment: I stripped it right down to just the grid with a textblock and no databinding. I still got the error. Any ideas?

Comment: I just removed the animation entirely. Between the different list boxes if i click on one then the other eventually i get the error again.

Comment: I've narrowed it down further. If I remove the remove the reference to the ListBoxItemControlTemplate(xaml posted above) which was being referenced from the item container template. It works. Does that make sense? can you see what it was within the itemcontroltemplate?